# Unicode string to Date format conversion error

Tags: python, unicode, python-datetime

I am a beginner in python automation with selenium bindings.
I have a Unicode string in the format like `Monday , December 12, 2016 , 00:00:23 PM`.

I am using the below command
 `datetime.strptime(date, "%A, %B %d, %Y, %I:%M:%S %p")` 
But I am getting error that time data doesn't match the format.

Please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried like this,

```
print datetime.datetime.strptime(u'Monday , DECEMBER 12, 2016 , 00:00:23 PM' , '%A , %B %d, %Y , %H:%M:%S %p')
```

and the output:

```
2016-12-12 00:00:23
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import time
time.strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y, %I:%M:%S %p", time.gmtime())
```

and make sure the space or other symbols are not missing.